# How do I create an inner drop shadow in text with php Imagick please?

Tags: shadow, imagick

I'm at the beginning of the learning curve with ImageMagick.
I have successfully created some text on a patterned background with outer light drop shadow to give the nice appearance of cut-out text.
To finish off the effect I need to give the text and inner dark drop shadow.
Are there any ImageMagick experts out there who can help with the php please?
This is my code so far which I'm happy with.

```
<?php
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
$background_layer = new Imagick('test_background.jpg'); # background image
$d = $background_layer->getImageGeometry();
$w = $d['width'];
$h = $d['height']; 
$text_layer = new Imagick();
$text_layer->newImage($w, $h, new ImagickPixel('none'));
$text_layer->setImageFormat('png');
$ImagickDraw = new ImagickDraw();
$ImagickDraw->setFillColor('#484848');
$ImagickDraw->setFont('Helvetica-Bold');
$ImagickDraw->setFontSize( 40 );
$ImagickDraw->setTextAlignment(2); // centre

$text_layer->annotateImage( $ImagickDraw, $w / 2, 50, 0, "Stuart's\niPhone" );

// create white drop shadow on it's own layer 
$shadow_layer_white = $text_layer->clone(); 
$shadow_layer_white->setImageBackgroundColor( new ImagickPixel( 'white' ) ); 
$shadow_layer_white->shadowImage( 70, .3, 1, 1 ); 

// composite original text_layer onto shadow_layer 
$shadow_layer_white->compositeImage( $text_layer, Imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, 0, 0 ); 
// composite shadow_layer (which now has text AND the shadow) onto image_layer 
$background_layer->compositeImage( $shadow_layer_white, Imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, 0, 0 ); 
echo($background_layer);
?>
```

I'm too new to post images so you can see what I have so far at

http://www.avforums.com/images/temptest.php

Any help you can give to add an internal dark drop shadow in the text would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are using Imagick not Imagemagick directly and may want to add that tag as well.

I do not use Imagick but [shadeimage](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.shadeimage.php) should do what you want in one go?

Comment: Thanks.  I edited my question.  That works pretty well.   $text_layer->shadeImage ( false , 135 , 35 );   The inner dark area is not as blurred as I'd like, but blurring that element is beyond me. I need the text layer to be transparent outside of the text.  How do I make the colour outside of the text transparent please?